# "do statistical inference" or "make statistical inference"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Shall I use *do* or *make* together with *[statistical inference](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/statistical_inference)*? Refering to [this site](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/doormake.html), *do* is used "when someone performs an action, activity or task" and *make* for "constructing, building or creating". In my understanding of "statistical inference" it can be both: the action of drawing conclusions and the results of this process. So which one shall I use?

Comment: *Make judgement* sounds more idiomatic than *do judgement* and I believe the same applies to inference.

Comment: "make" is more common, but you may also "carry out inferences".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20statistical%20inference%2Cmake%20statistical%20inference%2Cmake%20statistical%20inferences&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20statistical%20inference%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20statistical%20inference%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20statistical%20inferences%3B%2Cc0)***  shows a more usages of "make" vs "do". The two verbs appear to be used interchangeably with make the more commonly used between the two. From a more general perspective  I think "make" is more appropriate as it refers to the activities carried out to arrive at the final statistical results.

In general, referring to texts, analysis etc, both terms are used, but "make" is the more common.  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20statistical%20%2Cmake%20statistical%20&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20statistical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20statistical%3B%2Cc0) "do vs make statistical".